# iPhone UIFont boldFont With name

Tags: iphone, string, fonts, bold

I have looked at the headers for `UIFont` but it has all class methods and only one instance method and some useless properties. I would like to know how to set the font to have a font name, and bold font weight kinda like `[[UIFont alloc] initWithFontName:@"Courier New" weight:@"Bold" size:14];`. Thanks for any help in advance!

~Thommy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured out the answer, and that was to use the font-family's bolded version of the font:
`CourierNewPS-BoldMT` and that worked :

I found this out by using the `[UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:@"Courier New"]` method which returned an array of all the different variations of Courier New including, Bolded and Italic etc.

Answer (score 5):

I added a category to UIFont to do this, provided the Bold version of the font contains the word bold...

```
- (UIFont *)boldFont {
    NSArray *fontNames = [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:self.familyName];
    for (NSString *fontName in fontNames) {
        NSString *upperCaseFontName = [fontName uppercaseString];
        if ([upperCaseFontName rangeOfString:@"BOLD"].location != NSNotFound) {
            return [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:self.pointSize];
        }
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: not bad :D this could be rather useful.. but it's a lot of extra work for sure

Answer (score 3):

A Google search turns up this [list of available iPhone font names](http://ajnaware.wordpress.com/2008/10/24/list-of-fonts-available-on-the-iphone/).