# How do I create a bold UIFont from a regular UIFont?

Tags: ios, ios5, uikit

If I have a `UIFont` object, is it possible to convert it to bold? I don't know the font name, I just have a UIFont object. What I want is a function like

```
UIFont *boldFontFromFont(UIFont *input)
{
    return [input derivedFontWithFontWeight:UIFontWeightBold];
}
```

How can I change the code so that it works. (The code above does not work, I just made it up to illustrate the point.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @BB9z: really? this question is from 2013. Should we close it as duplicate now, 5 years later, because someone else asked a similar question again?

Comment: my mistake. The new one should be closed.

Comment: @BB9z: or, alternatively, we let both questions live? The UIFont.systemFont(ofSize:weight:) method did not exist in 2013. Technology changes all the time. My question was "*Living in 2013,* How do I create a bold UIFont from a regular UIFont **in Objective C**?" - the other question is "*Living in 2018,* How do I Set a Specific Font Weight for UILabel **in Swift**" - not really the same if you phrase it this way.

Comment: @BB9z: also, creating a font object with a specific weight from a font name and a font weight is not the same as wanting to create a font with a different weight from an already existing font object. It bothers me when questions are too eagerly closed as duplicates, just because they are 90% similar. It doesn't help anyone.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To get a bold font you need to pass a specific name of the font from a font family. You can get a font family name from a given font, then list all fonts from this family. In general, a bold font will contain "bold" in its name, but the format isn't strict and there could be variations like "Helvetica-BoldOblique", for example. You can start from this code:

```
- (UIFont *)boldFontFromFont:(UIFont *)font
{
    NSString *familyName = [font familyName];
    NSArray *fontNames = [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:familyName];
    for (NSString *fontName in fontNames)
    {
        if ([fontName rangeOfString:@"bold" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound)
        {
            UIFont *boldFont = [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:font.pointSize];
            return boldFont;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: hmm, there is a problem: for the systemFont, you have familyName == ".Helvetica NeueUI" and the fontNames array is an empty array :-/

Comment: @Michael I've tried `UIFont *boldFont = [self boldFontFromFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0]];`. NSLog output is: `<UICFFont: 0x758b320> font-family: "Helvetica-BoldOblique"; font-weight: bold; font-style: italic; font-size: 12px`

Comment: ok, did you use ios6? because i use ios 5. maybe the font system changed in ios6?

Comment: I get the same result on both iOS5 and iOS6 simulators.

Comment: on the simulator it works for me too. but on the device it does not. have you tested it on a device as well?

Comment: @Michael Yep, I got this ".Helvetica NeueUI" on device running iOS6 too. Found this (Twitter, @chockenberry): `iPhoneDevProtip: iPhone 4 system font is ".Helvetica NeueUI" with different lineHeight, ascender, descender metrics than "Helvetica Neue".`. Workaround: https://github.com/schwa/CoreTextToy/pull/35/files

Comment: omg, this is ugly. but it works, so I'll accept it. thanks. `if(font == [UIFont systemFontOfSize:font.pointSize]) {
        return [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:font.pointSize];
    } else if(font == [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:font.pointSize]) {
        return font;
    }`

Comment: I also found it useful to add some extra checks to ignore 'italic' and 'condensed' versions of the font (unless, of course, the reference font is itself italic/condensed).

Comment: This is problematic if you have more weight variations for a font than just bold. For example you could have "Helvetica Italic", "HelveticaBook Italic", "HelveticaLight Italic", etc.

Answer (score 100):

iOS 7 introduces a new [UIFontDescriptor](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIFontDescriptor_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class, which makes it a lot easier:

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:12];
NSLog(@"plain font: %@", font.fontName); // “HelveticaNeue”

UIFont *boldFont = [UIFont fontWithDescriptor:[[font fontDescriptor] fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits:UIFontDescriptorTraitBold] size:font.pointSize];
NSLog(@"bold version: %@", boldFont.fontName); // “HelveticaNeue-Bold”

UIFont *italicFont = [UIFont fontWithDescriptor:[[font fontDescriptor] fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits:UIFontDescriptorTraitItalic] size:font.pointSize];
NSLog(@"italic version: %@", italicFont.fontName); // “HelveticaNeue-Italic”

UIFont *boldItalicFont = [UIFont fontWithDescriptor:[[font fontDescriptor] fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits:UIFontDescriptorTraitBold | UIFontDescriptorTraitItalic] size:font.pointSize];
NSLog(@"bold & italic version: %@", boldItalicFont.fontName); // “HelveticaNeue-BoldItalic”
```

For people who got here looking for a Cocoa (macOS) equivalent, `UIFontDescriptor` comes from `NSFontDescriptor`, available since 10.3.

Answer (score 29):

And if you are looking for the **swift implementation**:

```
let normalFont = UIFont(name: "FONT_NAME", size: CGFloat(20))!
let boldFont = UIFont(descriptor: normalFont.fontDescriptor.withSymbolicTraits(.traitBold)!, size: normalFont.pointSize)
```

Hope this helps! Cheers!

Answer (score 9):

This is a very old thread but someone may be interested in how to do this in Swift 5 nowadays.

Easy like this:

```
var font: UIFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)
if let newDescriptor = font.fontDescriptor.withSymbolicTraits(.traitBold) {
    font = UIFont(descriptor: newDescriptor, size: font.pointSize)
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Attempting to derive the bold/italic font using font or family names no longer works correctly since iOS 7, due to the cryptic font family name of the system font. Below is a simple extension to derive the bold/italic font using the UIFontDescriptor class.

```
+(UIFont *) font:(UIFont *)font bold:(BOOL)bold italic:(BOOL)italic
{
    NSUInteger traits = 0;
    if (bold)
    {
        traits |= UIFontDescriptorTraitBold;
    }
    if (italic)
    {
        traits |= UIFontDescriptorTraitItalic;
    }
    return [UIFont fontWithDescriptor:[[font fontDescriptor] fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits:traits] size:font.pointSize];
}
```

Comment: Good point noted here: system fonts don't work exactly like other fonts.

Answer (score 2):

You can either use

```
[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12].
```

If you are using custom fonts you have to use the name directly

```
[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:17.0].
```

You can look up the possible font names with

```
[UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:@"American Typewriter"].
```

In this Post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15388946/436818 Ben M has an idea how to get the bold version dynamically. But extend the method to be sure to get the bold version (if it exists) because there are other bold versions like CondensedBold too.

Answer (score 2):

Since this question pops up when you search for bold UIFonts in **Swift**, here's a fresh answer:

```swift
extension UIFont {
    /// Returns a new font in the same family with the given symbolic traits,
    /// or `nil` if none found in the system.
    func withSymbolicTraits(_ traits: UIFontDescriptor.SymbolicTraits) -> UIFont? {
        guard let descriptorWithTraits = fontDescriptor.withSymbolicTraits(traits)
            else { return nil }
        return UIFont(descriptor: descriptorWithTraits, size: 0)
    }
}
```

Example:

```swift
myFont.withSymbolicTraits(.taitBold) // returns the bold version of myFont
```

Answer (score 2):

Nobody posted a solution which:

- is for Swift
- is an extension for `UIFont`
- doesn't do force unwraps
- uses the same point size as source font
- and only does what is asked in the question (create bold `UIFont` based on existing `UIFont`)

so I'm doing it:

```
import UIKit

extension UIFont {
    func boldFont() -> UIFont? {
        guard let boldDescriptor = fontDescriptor.withSymbolicTraits(.traitBold) else {
            return nil
        }

        return UIFont(descriptor: boldDescriptor, size: pointSize)
    }
}
```

Feel free to copy-and-paste!