# Set Specific Font Weight for UILabel in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uifont

When people have asked how to set a bold font, most people suggest:

```
let boldFont = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: ___)
```

But take a look at all the font weights that the standard system font offers:

[image: Xcode system font weights]

So my question is how do you set a light, semibold, or heavy font weight? The only way that I know how is:

```
sectionLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"TrebuchetMS-Bold" size:18];
```

However, I'm still asking because this isn't strongly typed. Most other class attributes are set by selecting from a fixed set of options and don't require passing a string that I could mistype. I guess I could set my own global enum... But any better ideas?

Comment: `class func systemFont(ofSize fontSize: CGFloat, weight: UIFont.Weight) -> UIFont`

Comment: You can use the initializer above and choose any font weight. i.e: `let systemFont: UIFont = .systemFont(ofSize: 32, weight: .thin)`

Comment: Look into UIFontDescriptor.

Comment: @rmaddy there is only one bold option in font descriptor `UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits.traitBold`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a bold UIFont from a regular UIFont?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16015916/how-do-i-create-a-bold-uifont-from-a-regular-uifont)

Comment: Hi, I'm the author of the suggested duplicate question here. I don't think this question is a duplicate of the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16015916/754705). I posted my reasoning in the comments on the other question.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I couldn't get the `UIFontDescriptor` to work with the font weight trait but there is another approach.

```
let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: .light)
```

Replace `.light` with whichever value you want from `UIFont.Weight` which basically matches the dropdown list shown in your question.

Comment: How to change font weight of a custom font programmatically ?

Comment: `UILable.font = UIFont(name: "MarkerFelt-Thin", size: 16)` just put `bold` or `thin` etc after the font name.

Comment: How can we set the weight of a custom font without changing it the system one?, I'm using Roboto Flex which is a variable font.

Answer (score 18):

You can use this extension. It assigns the weight to the fontDescriptor's weight key and instantiate your font with this new descriptor.

```
extension UIFont {
  func withWeight(_ weight: UIFont.Weight) -> UIFont {
    let newDescriptor = fontDescriptor.addingAttributes([.traits: [
      UIFontDescriptor.TraitKey.weight: weight]
    ])
    return UIFont(descriptor: newDescriptor, size: pointSize)
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not work for getting a regular weight font from a bold font, it still shows bold after adding regular weight trait. Test with New York font.

Comment: Test with New York and San Francisco Rounded fonts. It seems this only works for San Francisco font.

Answer (score 6):

The very old thread, but someone may be interested in how to do it in Swift.

`UIFont.Weight` defines all of the options:

- ultraLight
- thin
- light
- regular
- medium
- semibold
- bold
- heavy
- black

you can use simply like that, e.g.:

```
label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: size, weight: .bold)
```

or if you want to keep the previous size:

```
label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: label.font!.pointSize, weight: .bold)
```

Answer (score 1):

Even more:

```
let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: UIFont.Weight(500))
```

Comment: The iOS font weight is on a scale of -1 to 1, so this would return the heaviest possible font weight.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use system fonts, for Swift 5 a simple extension would look like this:

```
extension UIFont {
    func withWeight(_ weight: UIFont.Weight) -> UIFont {
        UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: pointSize, weight: weight)
    }
}
```