# Is it possible to Change the Regular font to Bold of UILable text?

Tags: swift, fonts, io, uilabel

I have a Label with custom font `Unica One-Regular`. Since, it is not available in bold font, I am getting problem to make it bold. Is there any way to make it bold?. Here is the font link.

[https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Unica+One?selection.family=Unica+One](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Unica+One?selection.family=Unica%20One)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a bold UIFont from a regular UIFont?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16015916/how-do-i-create-a-bold-uifont-from-a-regular-uifont)

Comment: In essence: if the font does not have a bold variation, then it's not possible, at least not in an easy way.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I’m on my iPhone but,
Please check the exact name of the font on Xcode, but this code should answer your question :

```
let attrs:[String:AnyObject] = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Unica One-Bold", size: 12)!]
        let boldString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "text", attributes:attrs)
let lbl = UILabel()
lbl.attributedText = boldString
```

Comment: Unica one-Regular is not the System font. It's google font. I have added this font to the project. And it is not available for Bold. If I use above code, I will get crash. Because, "Unica One-Bold" is not available.

Answer (score 0):

There is a more recent answer to this question at [Is it possible to increase the boldness of the font if the bold font file is not available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61367195/is-it-possible-to-increase-the-boldness-of-the-font-if-the-bold-font-file-is-not).

Short summary: if you have a list of font attributes, you can add a negative stroke width. For example (in Swift):

```
import AppKit

guard let chosenFont = NSFont(name: "VTypewriter Underwood", size: 24) else {
    print("No such font")
    exit(1)
}
var fontAttributes = [
    NSAttributedString.Key.font:chosenFont,
    NSAttributedString.Key.strokeWidth:NSNumber(value:-3.0)
]
let fakelyBoldedText = NSAttributedString(string:"Hello World", attributes:fontAttributes)
```

This is not optimal; it isn’t really bolding. But with low values for the stroke width (in my experiments, from about -3 to -5, possibly relative to the font width), it does look bolded.