# Is it possible to increase the boldness of the font if the bold font file is not available?

Tags: ios, fonts

I am using a custom font in an iOS app. I have added the font file for the regular variant. However, I do not have the bold font file.

Is it possible to increase the boldness of a font without having the bold font file?

Comment: Try using an `NSAttributesString` with a negative `strokeWidth` attribute.

Comment: @Yonat Your suggestion solved my problem. If you add a answer, I will accept it as the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an `NSAttributedString` with a negative `strokeWidth` attribute:

```swift
let range = NSRange(location:  0, length: attributedString.length
attributedString.addAttribute(.strokeWidth, value: NSNumber(value: -3.0), range: range))
```