# How do I set the weight of the font of a titleLabel of a UIButton?

Tags: swift, uibutton, uifont

I'm changing the font of the title of a UIButton like this:

```
self.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "SF UI Display", size: 30)
```

How do I then change the weight (I think XCode calls it "style")? It is currently defaulting to medium and I need it to be regular.

Comment: Included the steps in Answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a bold UIFont from a regular UIFont?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16015916/how-do-i-create-a-bold-uifont-from-a-regular-uifont)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Download the [The Regular Font](http://fontoteka.com/font/sf-ui-display-regular)

Try printing the Font Name:

```
 func printFonts() {
    let fontFamilyNames = UIFont.familyNames
    for familyName in fontFamilyNames {
        print("------------------------------")
        print("Font Family Name = [\(familyName)]")
        let names = UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: familyName)
        print("Font Names = [\(names)]")
    }
}
```

and then set it as follows:

```
self.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "pass the name of downloaded file", size: 30) //Pass the name of downloaded file here
```

**Note:-** After Downloading and Drag and Dropping into your Project, Do not forget to check the `Target Membership` is ticked or not, if not then tick it or it will not work for you

### Edit For setting appropriate name

Remove the existing font file by moving into trash and then

Change the file name after downloading to  **SFUIDisplayRegular.otf**

the tick the **target membership**

```
self.titleLabel?.font =  UIFont(name: "SFUIDisplayRegular", size: 20)
```

And it will work for you,

Cheers!

**See the Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks... I tried this but can't get it to pick up. I can get the main font to work but as soon as I use `"SF UI Display Regular"` it doesn't pick up at all. I've checked that Target Membership is correct for the app too. I've also tried things like `"Times New Roman"` (works) but `"Times New Roman Italic"` doesn't work.

Comment: lemme integrate this in my project

Comment: Thanks! Yes. it was: `"SFUIDisplay-Regular"`

Comment: Same for  "Times New Roman Italic" try removing the space and then insert it once again and may be it works for you, Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.it's working for you

```
self.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "SFUIDisplay-Regular", size: 30)
```

Answer (score 1):

After name of font use - and type the style name you need make sure that font file with that style name exist or support in xcode project.

```
struct Fonts {
        static let regular12 = UIFont.init(name: "OpenSans", size: 12) ?? UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)
        static let regular14 = UIFont.init(name: "OpenSans", size: 14) ?? UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
        static let regular16 = UIFont.init(name: "OpenSans", size: 16) ?? UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
        static let regular18 = UIFont.init(name: "OpenSans", size: 18) ?? UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)
        static let semiBold12 = UIFont.init(name: "OpenSans-Semibold", size: 12) ?? UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)
        static let semiBold14 = UIFont.init(name: "OpenSans-Semibold", size: 14) ?? UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
        static let semiBold16 = UIFont.init(name: "OpenSans-Semibold", size: 16) ?? UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
        static let bold12 = UIFont.init(name: "OpenSans-Bold", size: 12) ?? UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)
        static let bold14 = UIFont.init(name: "OpenSans-Bold", size: 14) ?? UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
        static let bold16 = UIFont.init(name: "OpenSans-Bold", size: 16) ?? UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
        static let regular20 = UIFont.init(name: "OpenSans", size: 20) ?? UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)
}
```

File Names that i have used in project for font are following:- Google Fonts - Open Sans Bold Italic.ttf, Google Fonts - Open Sans Bold.ttf, Google Fonts - Open Sans Semibold.ttf etc.